# Appending data from two different api calls inside single list

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-adapter, searchbar

I have integrated search bar inside action bar.I want suggestion list to display data from two different api calls so i am calling two apis inside onQueryTextChange() but the issue is that first data is displayed from first api call and then the data is replaced by the data of second api call.How can i display data to from two different api calls in the suggestion list of searchview?

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

        if(s.length()>=3) {
        String mStart = "";
      int mCount = 10;

            String[] columnNames = {"_id", "name", "userImage", "location"};
            final String[] temp = new String[5];
            final MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);
            SearchAPI.getSearchFeed(getApplicationContext(), s, mStart, mCount, mSettingsManager.getInstance().getAccessToken(), new APIResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Object response) {


                    searchResponses= (List<Video>) response;





                    for (Video searchResponse :searchResponses) {
                        temp[0] = Long.toString(id++);
                        temp[1] = searchResponse.getCaption();

                        temp[3] = searchResponse.getLocation();

                        cursor.addRow(temp);
                    }

                    mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SearchListAdapter(HomeActivity.this, cursor));

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(VolleyError error) {

                    if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {

                    }

                }
            });
            SearchAPI.getSearchUser(getApplicationContext(), s,mSettingsManager.getInstance().getAccessToken(), new APIResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Object response)
                {

                        userResponses = (List<User>) response;



                    for (User searchResponse :userResponses) {
                        temp[0] = Long.toString(id++);
                        temp[1] = searchResponse.getUserName();

                        temp[3] = searchResponse.getEmail();

                        cursor.addRow(temp);
                    }
                    mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SearchListAdapter(HomeActivity.this, cursor));


                }

                @Override
                public void onError(VolleyError error)
                {

                    if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {

                    }


                }
            });
        }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

1. Create a model with video and user.
2. Call your API's and create model objects.
3. Then add the model object list in to list view

Comment: read here http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=9

Comment: so i should create a new object class with both Video and User class setter and getter methods in it and then  add data from that object class to list

Comment: yes, create a model that includes both user and video fields, then call your both APIs, create model objects with response values, then you can show both user/video data within the same list with a appropriate view.

Comment: I followed your instruction and now having this issue..Glad if u can help me with this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353388/performing-different-action-on-clicking-on-the-item-of-list-that-contains-items